# how to use data binding for getting a value from user input and multiplay with contents with {{ ...}}

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, data-binding

i have a api response i.e price of product, {{price}}

i have a no .of products adding and reducing like

```
<div class="number-input"> <h2>Price: {{price }}</h2>
        <button onclick="this.parentNode.querySelector('input[type=number]').stepDown()" >-</button>
        <input #qty class="quantity" min="0" max="25" name="quantity" type="number" id="quan" ngModel>
         <button onclick="this.parentNode.querySelector('input[type=number]').stepUp()" class="plus">+</button>
      </div>
```

i need somthing like `{{price * input.value}}` how to achieve this in angular(11)

Comment: How are you returning/decorating your `price`. It should be as simple as defining a public variable of price with a value of 0 (`public price: number = 0`) and then in your api just update the value of price with the returned value.

Comment: I'd probably also use an `ngModel` on the input for 2 way binding. Then you could simply do `{{ price * quantity }}`

Comment: Identifier 'quantity' is not defined. The component declaration, template variable declarations, and element references do not contain such a member

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution please follow the below link.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-w6dvcq?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: error TS2363: The right-hand side of an arithmetic operation must be of type 'any', 'number', 'bigint' or an enum type.

33    <span>{{price * qty.value}}</span>
              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Comment: now i have edited my question, this is it ...in one component, and price is a responce from get req api..nothing more than this

Comment: I have updated my solution please follow that link you will understand @Raghuraman.

Comment: and im facing another small issue..like , i am getting a name from api response (say fresh vegetables), it is a category to be  displayed in navbar, i need t display that like fresh (linebreak) vegetables..i mean..any space character, it should break text...

Comment: i tried line-break: pre;..it is not working ..because i have many names from res,which is displayed in ng-for

Comment: Please post that question as question and put the link so that i can help.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231312/discussion-between-raghu-raman-and-saisurya).